# C++ coroutines: call a coroutine function without co_await

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

struct task is modified from https://github.com/Quuxplusone/coro/blob/master/include/coro/gor_task.h. I just change `suspend_always` [in Line 18](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/coro/blob/master/include/coro/gor_task.h#L18) to suspend_never.

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <exception>
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <variant>

template<class T>
struct task {
    struct promise_type {
        std::variant<std::monostate, T, std::exception_ptr> result_;
        std::experimental::coroutine_handle<void> waiter_;

        task get_return_object() { return task(this); }
        auto initial_suspend() { return std::experimental::suspend_never{}; } // Originally suspend_always
        auto final_suspend() {
            struct Awaiter {
                promise_type *me_;
                bool await_ready() { return false; }
                void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<void> caller) {
                    me_->waiter_.resume();
                }
                void await_resume() {}
            };
            return Awaiter{this};
        }
        template<class U>
        void return_value(U&& u) {
            result_.template emplace<1>(static_cast<U&&>(u));
        }
        void unhandled_exception() {
            result_.template emplace<2>(std::current_exception());
        }
    };

    bool await_ready() { return false; }
    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<void> caller) {
        coro_.promise().waiter_ = caller;
        coro_.resume();
    }
    T await_resume() {
        if (coro_.promise().result_.index() == 2) {
            std::rethrow_exception(std::get<2>(coro_.promise().result_));
        }
        return std::get<1>(coro_.promise().result_);
    }

    ~task() {
        coro_.destroy();
    }
private:
    using handle_t = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    task(promise_type *p) : coro_(handle_t::from_promise(*p)) {}
    handle_t coro_;
};

#include <stdio.h>

task<int> f2() {
    puts("enter f2");
    co_return 1;
}

task<int> f1() {
    puts("enter f1");
    int a = co_await f2();
    printf("f2 return: %d\n", a);
    co_return a;
}

int main() {
    f1();
}
```

```sh
$ clang++ -fcoroutines-ts -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ -lc++abi test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
enter f1
enter f2
fish: './test' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Because there's no `co_await`, I expect `f2 return: 1` should be printed and the program should exit normally, but it crashes with segfault. Why and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a coroutine function performs `co_await`, it halts that function's execution and schedules the resumption of that execution to someone else. This "someone else" ultimately depends on the expression being `co_await`ed on, the promise type of the coroutine function, and the future type returned by the coroutine.

So let's look at control flow here.

`f2` gets called. It executes, then terminates via a `co_return`. That means that the coroutine handle for `f2` is *complete*. This also means that the promise type's `final_suspend` will be called. Well, the coroutine machinery expects that `final_suspend` will return an awaitable type, which your `task::promise` provides.

Except... `task::promise::waiter_` is uninitialized. This is because only `await_suspend` assigns a value to `waiter_`. And nobody has `co_await`ed on the return value of `f2` yet. So until that happens, `waiter_` does not have a value.

So the moment `f2` gets called, you attempt to continue a coroutine handle that is at best `nullptr`, and thereby get a crash.

It would make more sense if `final_suspend`'s `Awaiter` type first checked to see if `waiter_` is `nullptr` (which means nobody is waiting on the coroutine yet) and if so, returns `true` from `await_ready`.

Comment: I changed `task::promise_type::final_suspend::Awaiter::await_ready` to `return !me_->waiter_;` but still got crash.

Comment: I have also tried making `Awaiter::await_suspend` return bool. No matter which value it returns, the program crashes.

Comment: @CarterLi: There may be other problems, but that's the first one I identified. Overall, I find myself confused as to exactly what it is that you're trying to accomplish here. For example, why are you doing `coro_.resume();` in `await_suspend`, a function which by its very name is about *suspending*, not executing a coroutine further?

Comment: You're right. `coro_.resume()` in `await_suspend` because the original version is lazily called. I forgot to remove this line. Thanks for your help!